# xctattachment symbol not found when running ios tests on aws device farm

Tags: ios, xctest, aws-device-farm

I have an iOS app and a set of unit tests for it (XCTests) and I would like to run these tests on aws device farm on an iOS device. AWS documentation is a bit vague but I found a great post describing steps in detail (http://cleanswifter.com/amazon-device-farm-xctest-tutorial/)
If I don't use XCTAttachment inside a XCTest - everything works fine. However if I want to use it - the app fails to load .xctest bundle with the following error:

```
2018-03-21 11:28:46.769 Testing[259:6945] The bundle “TestingTests” 
couldn’t be loaded. Try reinstalling the bundle.
2018-03-21 11:28:46.770 Testing[259:6945] 
(dlopen(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B59ACE41-3F1F-4209-983D- 
415BC47F118B/Testing.app/aatp/test-bundle.xctest/TestingTests, 265): 
Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_XCTAttachment
Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B59ACE41-3F1F-4209- 
983D-415BC47F118B/Testing.app/aatp/test-bundle.xctest/TestingTests
Expected in: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B59ACE41-3F1F- 
4209-983D-415BC47F118B/Testing.app/aatp/XCTest.framework/XCTest
in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B59ACE41-3F1F-4209-983D-415BC47F118B/Testing.app/aatp/test-bundle.xctest/TestingTests)
```

So for some reason it fails to find **XCTAttachment** symbol. The same code runs fine on simulator locally. It's a single view app built with XCode 9.2, iOS Deployment target is 10.3.

Has anyone had similar issue?

Comment: Can you determine if it is built remotely with Xcode 9.2, instead of Xcode 8.x?

Comment: AWS didn't support Xcode 9.2 at the time. That was the reason.